# Google Oauth Python requests: Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, google-api, python-requests

I try to communicate with Google API via Pythons requests module [requests module](http://www.python-requests.org/).
Receiving the authorization code works fine. Then I try to get an access token with the following code:

```
    params = { 
            'code': gauth, 
            'client_id': 'myid', 
            'client_secret': 'mysecret',
            'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:5000/googleauth',
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
            }
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    r = requests.post('http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', data=params)
```

"gauth" holds the authorization code received from the API. 
The problem that I am facing is that the API replies "405 Method Not Allowed".

I double checked and it is indeed sent as a POST request. It works fine when I use a tool such as [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) to fire the request manually.

To test, I created a dummy page in my app that displays the body contents of a POST request.
There I realized that when I send the request via Python requests, the redirect_uri is urlencoded (as shown in python-interpreter), but when I use Postman it is not (as shown in the Postman chrome tab). Could this be the cause of the problem? Or is it more likely that this is just a display issue (e.g. Postman decodes the urlencoded strings)?

As far as I know, it is not possible to deactivate urlencoding in requests, so I cannot test that.

Any hints are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After another hour I figured it out:
The request has to go to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` (httpS, not http).

If the request is sent to http:// it is redirected to https and in the process, the POST becomes a GET, hence the error message.